# Jersey Queryparam does not accept integer values with "+" sign

Tags: java, rest, encoding, jersey, jersey-2.0

I have a method as below

```
@GET
@Path("/display")
@Produces(value = { "application/json;qs=1", "application/xml;qs=.5" })
public Response displayItems(@QueryParam("limit") int limit,
                             @QueryParam("offset") int offset){
   //Code to display the requested number of Items
}
```

When i pass queryparams with +sign say,

```
 http://{host}:{post}/{context}/display?limit=+1&offset=+2
```

limit=+2 or offset=+2. It throws an error. When i tried debuging it s taking the values as {Space}2(So that it s not able to map {space}2 to int). It works fine with negative values(limit=-2 or offset=-2). Is this anything related to encoding? What am i missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, it's an encoding thing. '+' is a reserved character according to [RFC3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) which means that if you want it to be understood properly it must be percent encoded, which for '+' means encoding as '%2B'. The '-' character is explicitly unreserved and so Jersey understands it as is.

So, your URI that looks like...

```
http://{host}:{post}/{context}/display?limit=+1&offset=+2
```

should really be written...

```
http://{host}:{post}/{context}/display?limit=%2B1&offset=%2B2
```

Comment: Now i'm getting the value as +1(instead of {space}1). But still my query param limit is not accepting it as a Int. It is treating "+1" as string. Anyidea how to make it work without changing limit and offset to String in my code?

Comment: @Jeevi Have you tried making the parameter an Integer rather than an 'int'? My understanding is that `Integer.valueOf()` will be used to construct the Integer from a String.